# How would I edit .anim files in Blender?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, animator

I absolutely ***cannot*** stand animating in Unity.
I am making an FPS game with many weapons, and each weapon has four animations: running, jumping, aiming, and shooting. I would like to create a .anim file in Unity with the keyframes of the character and the weapon, and then edit that .anim file in Blender. How would I edit .anim files in Blender?

Comment: I presume you've started by [working your way through Blender animation tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+animate+in+blender&ia=web). Did you run into a specific problem along the way that we can help you solve, or a particular step you haven't found a tutorial to cover?

Comment: Well, I am making an FPS game with many weapons, and each weapon has four animations: running, jumping, aiming, and shooting. I would like to create a .anim file in Unity with the keyframes of the character and the weapon, and then edit that .anim file in Blender. @DMGregory

Comment: That sounds like a problem worth describing in detail in the body of your question.